# CancellationTokenSource with TimeSpan.From... or Constant time value?

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource

Are there any advantages in using TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) instead using a constant value when creating a CancellationToken?

```
CancellationTokenSource ctsTs = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
CancellationTokenSource ctsConst = new(1000);
```

Comment: Assume you don't know that `CancellationTokenSource` takes milliseconds (or time at all) as a parameter. You see `ctsConst` in some code. What do you suppose it does without investigating the constructor? Same question for `ctsTs`.

Comment: You shouldn't have "magic numbers" in your code. To avoid that here is to make it clear it's 1000 milliseconds. You can do that by using TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds or using a reasonably named `const int`. And the King of both: a `private static readonly TimeSpan _reasonablyNamedConstTimeSpan` :D

Comment: Okay, i see the readability here as a clear plus for this. Also avoiding magic numbers is definitely a plus. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: Using primitive types in place of more specific types is sometimes called *missing abstraction* or *primitive obsession*, and is considered an antipattern since it makes the code harder to read and understand, and increases the risk of mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

The helpful thing about using `TimeSpan` is that it tells the reader *what the number represents* (a span of time).

Another benefit of using `TimeSpan` is that you don't *have* to pass milliseconds - you can pass something more readable (at least to new programmers), like seconds:

```
CancellationTokenSource ctsTs = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

It tells the reader the unit of timespan is millisecond, but `1000` doesn't.

Comment: I think your answer is going in the right direction, but I'd suggest that it tells the reader the unit of time being passed, and also that a timeout period is being passed to `CancellationTokenSource`.

Answer (score 1):

From .NET side, there is no difference between the two. [CancellationTokenSource source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L286) In the end it just takes TimeSpan's TotalMilliseconds and that's how it's initalized.

by using Timespan.FromMilliseconds it's just more clear for the user/reader that it uses Milliseconds and the number 1000 is represented as ms. However, if you just leave 1000, user will have to take additional action in order to figure out if 1000 means minutes, seconds, or milliseconds. if you prefer not to use Timespan at all, another option would be to introduce separate constant for number 1000 and give it a more descriptive name.